# Does my data follow power law distribution? dummy approach in R

Tags: r, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, power-law

I am trying to test if my data fits the inverse power law distribution. Specifically, I am interested if my damaged area (Shape_Area) is somehow distance dependent?

I tried to apply examples from poweRlaw package.  However, the output of my Kolmogorov-Smirnof test is NULL: I am not sure, what I am doing wrong, how to identify the significance of the p-values, and, basically, how to interpret my results? How can I add the fitted curve to my scatter plot?

Here is my data:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lgb5ert88abcjcs/ring.csv?dl=0

and my code:

```
# read data
ring<-read.csv(file = "C:/Users/.../ring.csv", sep = ",")

 # plot the data
library(ggplot2)   
windows()
ggplot(ring, aes(x = distance, y = grad)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

```
# check out for power law
library("poweRlaw")

# load the data and create distribution object
data_pl = conpl$new(ring$Shape_Area)  # for continuous data

# estimate xmin and pars
est = estimate_xmin(data_pl)

data_pl$xmin <- est$xmin  # get xmin
data_pl$pars <- est$pars  # get alpha

# or
data_pl$xmin <- est

# check the KS statistics:
est$KS   # I've got back the NULL value??

# how likely is that my data are drawn from the power law distribution?
# need p-value

bs <- bootstrap_p(data_pl)
bs$p
```

Thank you !

Comment: Don't you have to invoke package='powerlaw' upon reading in the data? That's how the example in this link specifies it...  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/poweRlaw/vignettes/b_powerlaw_examples.pdf

Comment: yes, it is defined before the calculation

Comment: I see that it's in your library call but the example in the link provided makes it more explicit. I don't see where you're following the authors recommendation.

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but it looks like you never explicitly compare your data to the fitted power-law estimate, so the desired KS distance is never calculated. This documentation looks relevant: [Comparing Distributions (PDF)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/poweRlaw/vignettes/c_comparing_distributions.pdf), from the [CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/poweRlaw/index.html).

Comment: A general warning: In my experience, testing if data fits a power-law distribution just doesn't work very well in practice. I would not rely on it for anything important.